# Nexus 4 not recognized for development in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, android

I am an Android developer and use Nexus 4 for testing of my mobile applications. How ever the Nexus 4 (2012) version which was working fine until 4.4 in development mode , suddenly stopped working after update to 5.1 . Though the device is being recognized in MTP , not working for development mode.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to be working again by installing the Google drivers from 
http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html
and following the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972658/adb-driver-and-windows-8-1